# How to escape xml for use in perl multiline search and replace?

Tags: regex, xml, bash, perl

I want to use perl to replace a key-value pair in an xml file, but I am having problems escaping the xml from the regex parser.
All this is supposed to run from a bash script. So I have two variables:

```
macDefault="<key>DefaultVolume</key>\
                <string>91630106-4A1F-4C58-81E9-D51877DE2EAB</string>"

winDefault="<key>DefaultVolume</key>\
                <string>EBD0A8B3-EE3D-427F-9A83-099C37A90556</string>"
```

And I want perl to replace the occurrence of the value $macDefault with the value of $winDefault in the file config.plist

Unfortunately

```
perl -0pe  's/'"$macDefault"'/'"$winDefault"'/' config.plist
```

does not work, as perl reports:

```
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at -e line 1.
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/<key>DefaultVolume</key>                <string>91630106-4A1F-4C58-81E9-D51877DE2EAB</string"
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at -e line 1.
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "<string>EBD0A8B3"
        (Missing operator before EBD0A8B3?)
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "427F"
        (Missing operator before F?)
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "9A83"
        (Missing operator before A83?)
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "099C37A90556"
        (Missing operator before C37A90556?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/<key>DefaultVolume</key>                <string>91630106-4A1F-4C58-81E9-D51877DE2EAB</string"
Illegal octal digit '9' at -e line 1, at end of line
Illegal octal digit '9' at -e line 1, at end of line
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-3/

Comment: I guess after the interpolation, some regex delimiter conflicts were discovered, i.e. with `/` of the closing tag. To fix that you need to escape all meta characters before hand, or use a different delimiter, `~` for example.

Comment: Don't attempt to generate Perl code from the shell!!! Pass the values as command-line arguments of env vars

Answer (score 1):

It's *always* better to use a proper XML parser than try to hack something together with regular expressions

Here's an example using [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM), because it often gets overlooked in favour of [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) or [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML)

I've had to wrap your XML sample in a `<root>` element to make it well-formed. I'm sure the real document looks nothing like this, but it's the best guess I've got and the real case isn't likely to require the Perl to be changed a great deal

The input file is expected as a parameter on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $xml = do { local $/; <> };
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse($xml);

my $keys   = $dom->find('key')->grep(sub { $_->text eq 'DefaultVolume' });
my $string = $keys->[0]->next;
$string->content('EBD0A8B3-EE3D-427F-9A83-099C37A90556');

print $dom, "\n";
```

#### output

```
<root>
  <key>DefaultVolume</key>
  <string>EBD0A8B3-EE3D-427F-9A83-099C37A90556</string>
</root>
```

Comment: I was using cygwin perl, which cannot cleanly install modules with cpan. I Installed ActivePerl, but it seems that ActivePerl and cygwin perl conflict if installed on the same Windows machine. I was trying to avoid this kind of overhead. I expect that the administration effort will be worse then effort needed to get a safe and working regex for this one-off problem.

Comment: @Charlweed: The difference is that you only have to install the module *once* and you will have a solution for any XML problem that you may come across. I'm not familiar with Cygwin Perl but you may get some mileage out of bypassing cpan and following the instructions in [perlmodinstall](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html). And [here's a perlmonks post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=745457) about it that may help. If you have a choice then I recommend you go with Strawberry Perl, which has many non-core modules as well as a make utility and compilers

Comment: For future readers: I eventually got ActivePerl to work alongside cygwin, but I did have to edit my account's bashrc/profile, delete my local .cpan dir, edit cygwin's /etc bash settings, clear the Windows registry of the previous ActivePerl settings, and edit ActivePerls's new registry entries.

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet this would work:

```
macDefault="91630106-4A1F-4C58-81E9-D51877DE2EAB"

winDefault="EBD0A8B3-EE3D-427F-9A83-099C37A90556"

perl -0pe  's/'"$macDefault"'/'"$winDefault"'/'
```

or, accommodating your comment:

`perl -0pe 's?(<key>DefaultVolume</key>\s*<string>)'"$macDefault"'(\s*</string>)?$1'"$winDefault"$2'?s' config.plist`

Noting the /s for multiline matching.

Comment: No, because both UUIDs appear more then one in the xml file. I can only math on the multiline string.

Comment: Not that I disagree with @Borodin, but a command line solution has it's place, especially if you want to be minimally invasive of your platform or just don't want to build a system manipulating XML files (yes, I've been there).

Comment: I did want to point out that in your original version you were not matching on a multiline string.

Comment: This is probably the answer that I wanted, but I have already installed ActivePerl and Mojo::DOM.

Comment: sorry it took so long.